# Reduce list to fixed size with fixed interval sampling

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a simple way in Python 3(.6) to reduce a variable size list to a length of 4 while keeping it in order and returning the first item, the item at the 33% position, the item at the 66% position and the last item?

So for example if I have:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

I want it reduced to:

`[1, 3, 7, 10]`

Comment: Your input list length will always be greater than 4? If not what is expected output from a list with fewer elements

Comment: `l[::int(len(a_list)/3)]`, will return `[1, 4, 7, 10]`.I am not sure if you are finding a way to cut a slice like this.

Comment: @kuro I will only use this function if the length is more than 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
_= [ n for k,n in enumerate(l) if k+1 in 
       [1,round(len(l)*0.33),round(len(l)*.66),len(l)]
   ]
```

were `l` is the original list.

Comment: works great, thanks! This is along the lines of what I had thought up myself. I was wondering if maybe there was an easier-to-use built-in function I didn't know about but I guess not.